# How do I read a column as a categorical in CSV.jl

Tags: julia

I have tried many variations of the following:

```
f = CSV.File(file, delim="\t", 
             header=["C" * string(i) for i in 1:6], 
             types=Dict("C1"=>CategoricalArray))
```

In pandas I would use the string "category" to describe the datatype.

Alternatively, if I want to build a dataframe from scratch, can I say something like

```
df = DataFrame(Chromosome = CategoricalArray[], Start = Int64[], End = Int64[], Name = Int64[], Score = Int64[], Strand = CategoricalArray[])
```

I have tried it, but then I get the error:

`ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Error adding chr8 to column :Chromosome. Possible type mis-match.`

Comment: The problem is that `CategoricalArray` is an abstract type. I would recommend you to convert `:C1` to categorical after reading-in the data. You have a switch that makes columns that have a lot of duplicates categorical, but I guess this is not what you need. If the feature of forcing conversion of a column to categorical is something that you really think is worth adding could youl please make an Issue.

Comment: I will consider it. Both pandas and R has this option. R had it as the default setting for a long time even IIRC.

Comment: CSV.jl also has this option by default (keyword name `categorical`), but it is triggered only if the % of unique values seen during type detection is less than 67%.

Comment: In R the default setting was (/is) to have any non-numerical columns be categorical, because R is very focused on statistical testing.

Answer (score 0):

Like Bogumil said, the best thing is probably to use the flag

```
CSV.read(..., categorical = true)
```

For columns with mostly unique data, this will add overhead, but is the best way to do it for now.